# Union of Interiors is Subset of Interior of Union

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I'm teaching my self topology using a book I found. This is the forth part of a 4 part question. links to other parts: [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1851554/closure-of-intersection-is-subset-of-intersection-of-closures), [two](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1851655/closure-of-union-contains-union-of-closures/1851732?noredirect=1#comment3790969_1851732), [three](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1858590/intersection-of-interiors-contains-interior-of-intersection)
.

I'm trying to prove the following problem from a book I found:

> Let $X$ be a topological space and let $\mathscr{A}$ be a collection of subset of $X$. Prove 
>  $int( \bigcup \limits_{A \in \mathscr{A}} A)\supseteq \bigcup \limits_{A \in \mathscr{A}} int(A)$

I want to know if my proof is valid, and before i prove it I will given an example of $int( \bigcup \limits_{A \in \mathscr{A}} A)\supset \bigcup \limits_{A \in \mathscr{A}} int(A)$.

> Example of $int( \bigcup \limits_{A \in \mathscr{A}} A)\supset \bigcup \limits_{A \in \mathscr{A}} int(A)$.

Let: $\mathscr A =\{[1,2] , [2,3]\}$. So then, $int( \bigcup \limits_{A \in \mathscr{A}} A) =(1,3)$  and $ \bigcup \limits_{A \in \mathscr{A}} int(A)=(1,3)\setminus{2}. $

> Proof of: $int( \bigcup \limits_{A \in \mathscr{A}} A)\supseteq \bigcup \limits_{A \in \mathscr{A}} int(A)$

To prove this, I will use 3 corollaries, that will not be proven here. 

(1) $ \forall  S \in \mathscr S : S \subseteq  \bigcup \limits_{S \in \mathscr{S}} S$; Any individual set in a collection is a subset of the union of the entire collection.

(2) $U \subseteq V \implies int(U) \subseteq int(V)$ : **IF** U is a subset of V, **THEN** the interior of U is a subset of the interior of V.

(3) $\forall X \in \mathscr X : X \subseteq  Y  \implies  \bigcup \limits_{X \in \mathscr{X}} X \subseteq  Y$: **IF** If every subset in a collection is a subset of Y **THEN** the union of the collection is also a subset of Y.

**Proof:** Let, $\mathscr A$ be any collection of sets in a topological space, and let $A$ be any individual  set in the collection.

$ \forall  A \in \mathscr A : A \subseteq  \bigcup \limits_{A \in \mathscr{A}} A$; (1, $S=A$)

$ \forall  A \in \mathscr A : int(A)
\subseteq 
int(\bigcup \limits_{A \in \mathscr A} A )$;
(2,  $U = A $ and $V= \bigcup \limits_{A \in \mathscr A} A $ and )

$\bigcup \limits_{A \in \mathscr{A}} int(A)
\subseteq 
int( \bigcup \limits_{A \in \mathscr{A}} A)$ ;
(3, $X=int(A)$ and $Y=int(\bigcup \limits_{A \in \mathscr A} A )$)

QED

Is this proof valid? Am I using the  $\forall$ symbol correctly?

Comment: Your proof is valid, though you should better write 
$$∀A∈A:A⊆B$$
 or 
$$A⊆B \text{ for all }A∈A$$
 instead of 
$$\color{red}{\forall A\subseteq B}$$

Comment: The same proof applies to the closure operator, or any operator with the property (2). Such an operator is said to be *monotone* (or *monotonic*, or *order-preserving*).

Comment: Parts 1 and 2 are for the closure. I proved those is a less elegant manner. I used the answer by @user254665 for part 2, to do 3 and 4. I spent over 2 weeks thinking about this problem, and mainly thanks to user254665 I feel like a finally have a grasp on this concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answers to questions: Yes and No, in that order.  For the second question, your mistake is that you are overlapping the quantifier scope with the formula.  Example: you write the first step of the proof (with justification removed) as:

$ \forall  A \subseteq  \bigcup \limits_{A \in \mathscr{A}} A$

What you should be doing is quantifying the variable separately first, then giving the condition satisfied by the variable, i.e:

$ \forall A \in \mathscr{A}$ : $ A \subseteq  \bigcup \limits_{A \in \mathscr{A}} A$

Similarly, the second step should be written:

$\forall A \in \mathscr{A}$ : $ int(A)
\subseteq 
int(\bigcup \limits_{A \in \mathscr A} A )$

and so forth.

Comment: thanks, i just made the edits. I think its good now.