# Union and intersection of exterior

Tags: general-topology

I know that $A^e\cup B^e\neq (A \cap B)^e$ but how to show that $A^e\cup B^e\subseteq(A \cap B)^e$?

Comment: $A^e$ means the exterior of $A$?

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan, yes.

Comment: $p\in A^e$ iff there is an open $U$ with $p\in U$ and $U\cap A =\phi.$  If such $p$ and $U$ exist then $U$ is an open set with $p\in U$ and $U\cap (A\cap B)=\phi,$ implying $p\in (A\cap B)^e.$... So $p\in A^e\implies p\in (A\cap B)^e.$... Similarly $p\in B^e\implies p\in (A\cap B)^e.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, $A^e=\operatorname{int}(A^c)$, where $A^c$ is the set complement of $A$. De Morgan's Law says that $A^c\cup B^c=(A\cap B)^c$. Hence,
$$\begin{align}
A^e\cup B^e&=\operatorname{int} (A^c)\cup \operatorname{int} (B^c)\\
&\subset \operatorname{int} (A^c\cup B^c)\\
&=\operatorname{int}(A\cap B)^c\\
&=(A\cap B)^e
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you for answer but the problem with this is that now I have to prove that $\operatorname{int} A^c\cup \operatorname{int} B^c
\subset \operatorname{int} (A^c\cup B^c)$.

Comment: @gbd If you are interested, you cand [read this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1858611/union-of-interiors-is-subset-of-interior-of-union)

Comment: @gbd Anyway, we know that $\operatorname{int}(A^c)\subset A^c$ and $\operatorname{int}(B^c)\subset B^c$ implying that $$\operatorname{int}(A^c)\cup \operatorname{int}(B^c)\subset A^c\cup B^c$$ and because $\operatorname{int}(A^c\cup B^c)$ is the largest open subset of $A^c\cup B^c$, we get  $$\operatorname{int}(A^c)\cup \operatorname{int}(B^c)\subset \operatorname{int}(A^c\cup B^c)\subset A^c\cup B^c.$$

Comment: Thank you this is really helpful.

Comment: @gbd You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\overline {A\cup B}=\bar A\cup \bar B\supset \overline {A\cap B}$ , we have $$x\in (A^e\cup B^e)\iff (x\not \in \bar A\land x\not \in \bar B)\iff$$ $$\iff x\not \in {\bar A\cup \bar B}\iff x\not \in \overline {A\cup B}\implies$$ $$\implies x\not \in \overline {A\cap B}\iff x\in (A\cap B)^e.$$