# Let A and B be subsets of R, prove that int(A ∪ B) ⊂ int(A) ∪ int(B)

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

$x\in int(A \cup B)$ implies that there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)\subset(A \cup B),$
hence, $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\subset A  \cup  (x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\subset B$, implies $x\in int(A)\cup int(B)$.
Is this true?

And how to prove that $int(A ∪ B)$ ⊂ $int(A)$ ∪ $int(B)$?

Comment: You can (easily) prove the reverse inclusion, not this one, which doesn’t generally hold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is false. If $A$ is the set of all rational numbers and  $B$ is the set of all irrational numbers then $A$ and $B$ have no interior but the interior of $A \cup B$ is $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Thank you. But for general solution, how do I prove that int(A ∪ B) ⊂ int(A) ∪ int(B)?

Comment: @JASMINE In general, this inclusion is not true as shown by this answer. Only the reverse inclusion is true in general. [See](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3350947/int-s-cup-int-t-subseteq-ints-cup-t?rq=1).